# How to keep Google Assistant Behavior but also trigger IFTTT

Tags: google-now, ifttt

I know you can make custom Google Assistant triggers that will invoke IFTTT. But I want to make a custom trigger that will do something but /also/ keep the default Google Assistant behavior. Is there a way to do this?

Description of my actual goal: I speak German as much as possible at home with my daughter. But there are times where I don't know a word, so I can say "OK Google, what is $word in German?" and it will speak it to me. This is very useful.

Then I manually add that word to my vocabulary list to study it.

I would like to write my own Python/Node microservice that will receive the word and generate flashcards (do a lookup on Linguee for sample sentences, for example) in my study program automatically.

But I would also like to keep the Google Assistant behavior that reads the translation back to me on my phone.

So is there a way to accomplish this? Basically instead of having a trigger invoke Google Assistant, I'd like it to do that *and also* do a second behavior (issue a POST request to a custom URL).

Thank you.